# $ \int_{0}^{f(x)} t^2dt = x^3(1+x)^2 \: $ and $ \: \int_{0}^{x^2(1+x)} g(t)dt = x \: \forall x\in [0,\infty).$ $f(2)+g(2) = ? $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $ f\: \colon \: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R} \quad \textrm{and} \quad g\: \colon \: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}   \quad       \textrm{be continuous functions satisfying }   \: \colon  $

$$ \int_{0}^{f(x)} t^2dt \: =\: x^3(1+x)^2 \quad \textrm{and} \quad \int_{0}^{x^2(1+x)} g(t)dt \: =\: x \quad \forall \:x\in [0,\infty).\\$$

Then $f(2)+g(2) \:\:=\:\: ? \\$

**My solution:**

$\int_{0}^{f(x)} \: t^2dt\:=\: x^3(1+x)^2\:.$ As $t^2$ is continuous everywhere $\:,\:\therefore$ we can apply fundamental theorem of calculus and get $\colon\\$

$\frac{1}{3}(f(x))^3=x^3(1+x)^2\:\Rightarrow f(x)=3^\frac{1}{3}x(1+x)^\frac{2}{3}.\: \\$

Thus $f(2)=3^\frac{1}{3}*2*3^\frac{2}{3}=6.\\$

By Leibniz rule : $\: \frac{d}{dx}\:\int_{f_{1}x}^{f_{2}x}g(t)dt=g(f_{2}x)f_{2}^{\prime}(x)-g(f_{1}x)f_{1}^{\prime}(x). \:$

Applying this to given equation $\: \int_{0}^{x^2(1+x)} g(t)dt \: =\: x \quad$ we get : $ \\$

$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{0}^{x^2(1+x)} g(t)dt=\frac{d}{dx}x \Rightarrow g(x^2+x^3)\frac{d}{dx}(x^2+x^3)-g(0)(0)=1\\ \Rightarrow (2x+3x^2)g(x^2+x^3)=1 \Rightarrow g(x^2+x^3)=\frac{1}{2x+3x^2}.\:\:\\$

We need to find $g(2) \: , \therefore (x^2+x^3)=2 \Rightarrow x=1 \: $on solving $.\:\\$

Putting $x=1\:$ in above equation we get $\: \colon \: g(2)=\frac{1}{2+3}=\frac{1}{5}.\\$

Thus $f(2)=6 \:$ and $\: g(2) = \frac{1}{5} \:,\therefore f(2)+g(2)=6+\frac{1}{5}=\frac{31}{5} \:.\\$

But the answer has been given as 11 instead of what i got. Coz $\:"5+6"\:$ is $\:11\:$ i guess, but i don't see why that will be the case. Can someone please verify if i am making a mistake and point it out , or is the solution mentioned in my book wrong...many thanks.